# How to change color text in menu, using Nativescript

Tags: angular, menu, nativescript, grid-layout

In this [play](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=xMQTRw) I have a demo from my project.

I want to change color text in menu when I select it.

In html I used this code:

```
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal" class="foot" backgroundColor="#eae8e8" padding="10 5 10 5">
        <StackLayout (tap)="gofp()" width="45%" textAlignment="center">
            <Label  text="Home">

            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout (tap)="gosettings()" width="55%" textAlignment="center">
            <Label  text="Settings">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

I try a function like this:

```
declare var $: any;

$(function () {
    $("#myMenu label").click(function () {
        $("#myMenu label").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

but show this error:

> $ is not defined

Can you give me any idea, how to change color text when I select it?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRs9z.png)

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use jquery in an angular app? You really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Can you ask me any idea please?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use jQuery. The easiest way is to use ngClass. `[ngClass]="{ 'active': itemActive }`. When you then (tap) the label you can set `itemActive` to true and then you have the `active` class on the Label.

Pass the event so you know which item you clicked and add the class accordingly.

Comment: Can you  write something in demo please?

Comment: @w.site did not try this myself but it might be what you're looking for. Obviously code suck as (click) should be switched to (tap)
http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/add-class-to-active-element-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm a relatively new Nativescript/Angular developer myself, but to my knowledge, you don't need to use jQuery to make a change like this (and I'm not sure if it works either, but I could be wrong). Using `ViewChild` and `ElementRef`, you can access the properties of the element and change them directly; try referring to and tweaking [this playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=H60Ffi&v=3) to get the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need something else, something like in image in post.

Comment: You were modifying `background-color` in your playground, so the playground I made modified `backgroundColor`. It looks like you want to modify the `color` property instead though; try replacing `backgroundColor` with that or other properties you need.

Comment: Yes I modify, but that I want is: when I open app default selected is in tab Home (color red), and other menu are color black (for example). When I select menu Settings I want to change color, Settings to red, and Home + other menu to black color.

Comment: Something like this menu: https://www.google.al/search?biw=1920&bih=974&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=6Zd1W_P3NomQmwX8sLeoBQ&q=how+to+change+text+color+menu+in+nativescript&oq=how+to+change+text+color+menu+in+nativescript&gs_l=img.3...8629.20031.0.20277.29.26.3.0.0.0.120.2582.17j9.26.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.7.556...0j0i8i30k1j0i24k1j0i67k1j0i30k1j35i39k1.0.Rg1pgGK8awk#imgdii=sAnzA0dvAfsEnM:&imgrc=Cf7DOssb2IfYWM:

Comment: Based on what I've mocked in the playground, you should be able to figure it out from there by experimentation and consulting the Nativescript docs. To get started, try setting the `backgroundColor` of your default tab in the HTML.